# How can I update an exisiting image with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update an existing image in my database using mysql query.

This is my edit.php where i edit user info

```
<?php
  require_once "config.php";

    if(isset($_GET['edit']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE id=$id");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    }

    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
      $newText = $_GET['voornaam'];
      $newText2 = $_GET['tussenvoegsel'];
      $newText3 = $_GET['achternaam'];
      $newText4 = $_GET['stemsoort'];
      $newText5 = $_GET['adres'];
      $newText6 = $_GET['postcode'];
      $newText7 = $_GET['plaats'];
      $newText8 = $_GET['telefoon'];
      $newText9 = $_GET['mobiel'];
      $newText10 = $_GET['email'];
      $newText11 = $_GET['status'];
      $newText12 = $_GET['lid_sinds'];
      $newText13 = $_GET['lid_tot'];

      $id    = $_GET['id'];
      $res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE id=$id");
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
      $sql     = "UPDATE user_data SET voornaam='$newText', tussenvoegsel='$newText2', achternaam='$newText3', stemsoort='$newText4', adres='$newText5', postcode='$newText6', plaats='$newText7', telefoon='$newText8', mobiel='$newText9', email='$newText10', status='$newText11',lid_sinds='$newText12',lid_tot='$newText13' WHERE id=$id";
      $res   = mysqli_query($link,$sql)
                                      or die("Could not update".mysqli_error($link));
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
    }
  ?>
```

And this is how I upload images to a folder and then into mysql database

```
 <?php

  $msg = "";
  $css_class = "";

  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');

  if (isset($_POST['save-user'])) {
    echo "<pre>", print_r($_FILES['profileImage']['name']),"</pre>";

    $bio = $_POST['bio'];
    $profileImageName = time() . '_' . $_FILES['profileImage']['name'];

    $target = 'images/' . $profileImageName;

      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profileImage"]["tmp_name"], $target)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (profile_image, bio) VALUES ('$profileImageName','$bio')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
          $msg = "image uploaded";
          $css_class = "alert alert-success";
        }else {
          $msg = "Database Error: Failed to save user";
          $css_class = "alert alert-danger";
        }
      } else {
        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
        $css_class = "alert alert-danger";
      }
    }

 ?>
```

How can I combine the two and let a user edit his uploaded profile image? Thanks for helping out

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.